# How to check field from json 1 to field from json 2 using karate framework

Tags: karate

I have two json -> 1 is a json response which has a set of key/values and the values from this json 1 is set to different key in json 2.I want to compare the keys from json 1 and json 2 and see if the values are same. How can this be done using Karate framework.

Example:

Json 1
{
"details": {
"employee": "tester",
"id": "1234",
"salary": "20000"
}

}

Json 2

{
"information": {
"name": "tester",
"reference": "1234",
"amount": "20000"
}

}

So in above value of details.employee from json 1 is set to information.name is json 2 . How to validate such scenario is Karate framework please